# Can DNN skins and modules be deployed through TFS?

Tags: deployment, dotnetnuke

We're in the midst of a switch from Sitefinity to DNN Evoq Content, and I'm still wrapping my heads around how to deploy modules and skins.

I know DNN wants you to create a zip file to be uploaded to install a module or a skin, but is there another way to deploy them? Currently, we develop our modules for Sitefinity within the web project, and deploy the whole site using TFS. Could this be done a similar way for DNN?

Also, we have a load balanced web farm in production. If I'm logged into web server A and upload a skin, will web servers B, C, and D receive the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the ZIP files into

/install/module/ or /install/skin/

then call your website/install/install.aspx?mode=installresources and DNN will install any ZIP files in the various sub folders of the install directory.

As for syncing across multiple webservers, that is something you have to configure. I believe DNN Corp still recommends using a NAS for file storage, all web servers pointing to the same NAS, instead of doing file synchronization as DNN itself won't do syncing.